# Как отображать, скачивать и сохранять изображения в память телефона?

Tags: java, android, изображения

Моя задача: спарсить `JSON` из интернета, положить их в `SQLite` (это я сделал), но я сохранил только пути к изображению, но не сами изображения.
Мне нужно скачать изображения из интернета, и при последующем запуске приложения загружать все эти картинки из памяти телефона. Как это сделать новичку? Может быть есть какие-то готовые библиотеки для такого рода задач? Подскажите пожалуйста
Я использую: `Retrofit 2`, `Active Android`, `SQlite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, есть библиотеки и да, лучше всего использовать их. Вот пример предварительной загрузки изображений в кэш по ссылке либой [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide):

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load("IMAGE_URL")
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                Log.e("TAG", "error while preload image by Glide");
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                  Log.d("onResourceReady: " + resource.getIntrinsicWidth() + "/" + resource.getIntrinsicHeight());
                return false;
            }
        })
        .preload();
```

После этого отображать её так (изображение возьмётся из кэша):

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load("IMAGE_URL")
        .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: я не очень понял код выше, я так понял вы оверрайдите метод Glide.with() ? Я не могу найти в интернете способ загрузки изображений на память телефона с помощью глайда, может быть у вас есть под рукой пару ссылок?

Comment: @ВиталийБелоусов, нет, никаких овверрайдов тут нет. Если вы имеете в виду запись картинки в конкретный файл на диске, то `Glide` так не умеет, насколько я знаю. Но вы можете сделать это взяв картинку из аргумента метода `onResourceReady` и записать её самостоятельно в файл.

Comment: как мне лучше реализовать оффлайн режим? чтобы один раз загрузил изображение из интернета и в последующем не нужен был интернет для того, чтобы посмотреть картинки. Но также с учетом того, что количество картинок может увеличиваться, картинки могут меняться и т.д.

Comment: @ВиталийБелоусов, ну... В ответе как раз это и описано. Для каждого адреса картинки вызывайте первый кусок кода. А для отображения - второй. Первый загрузит картинку в кэш, второй отобразит из него или загрузит его в кэш и оттуда отобразит, если в кэше нет картинки

Comment: не понял, а зачем мне тогда использовать первый вариант (большой кусок кода), если можно использовать второй, который работает точно также, но меньше кода?

Comment: @ВиталийБелоусов, т.к. второй способ - для отображения. В частности ImageView нужно. И больше там всего на одну строку - слушатель с логгированием можно опустить.

Comment: какой вариант предпочтительнее использовать? первый или второй?

Comment: @ВиталийБелоусов, они для разных целей. Если отображать - второй. Если только загрузить - первый.

Comment: спасибо! почитал в интернете про это, я так понял что изображение при загрузке сразу кешируется по умолчанию (если эту функцию не отключить). Надеюсь я правильно понял. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

> Как это сделать новичку? Может быть есть какие-то готовые библиотеки
>   для такого рода задач?

Попробуйте использовать библиотеку [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) для загрузки и [кеширования](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics) изображений

Comment: буду пробовать, спасибо!